# Leveraging a facebook app for SEO

Tags: seo, facebook, nofollow, facebook-application

I am contemplating writing a facebook app for my website. I want to know how I can use the app to aid with Google ranking.

More specifically, are there things I can do (an obvious one being placing links back to my website etc) to increase visibility of my site?

Also, will the links from my fb app to my website be "nofollow"? (I suspect the amnswer is yes), in that case (if links back to my site are "nofollow"), will I benefit much (from an SEO POV) by implemnting the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEO links from Facebook, Delicious, Digg are useful to increase Google PR?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/seo-links-from-facebook-delicious-digg-are-useful-to-increase-google-pr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the pages in your Facebook app be indexed and crawled by search engines? AFAIK they cannot be as you must be logged in to see apps and other user content. So these links will have no SEO value for you.